# Conversion nvarchar to decimal

Tags: sql, type-conversion, sql-server-ce-3.5

```
SELECT NOM ,Sum(CAST(SOLDE AS float)) AS _solde
FROM tab 
WHERE NUM_CLIENT='550322' 
GROUP BY NOM
```

I have a result without comma ,SOLDE is  something like that 66,11 i want a result respecting a comma .

Comment: what Type is SOLDE ? Add schema, some data sample and expected results, please

Comment: Can you retry the wording for your question?  It does not make sense.

Comment: `SOLDE is something like that 66,11` how can you convert that to float?

Comment: @Rahul Some parts of the world use a comma as a decimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server does not respect locale settings for varchar to number conversions, so you will need to replace the comma with a decimal first.

```
SELECT NOM ,Sum(CAST(REPLACE(SOLDE,',','.') AS float)) AS _solde
FROM tab 
WHERE NUM_CLIENT='550322' 
GROUP BY NOM
```